# In Excel how to present or display only colums that has data filled in as row

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an excel file with "marks" for each "roll number" under "classes".
Few of the students did not attend couple of exams so mark for those subjects for those students is absent.

Sample Data (as CVS):

```
CLASS,ROLL,ENG,MAT,SCI,ODI,HIN,SOC,ART
V,10,20,10,19,,5,12,
V,11,18,9,16,6,,,
V,12,,5,10,,,12,1
VI,24,,6,8,,,,9
VI,25,5,,,8,,10,14
VI,26,1,,6,,,8,20
```

Is there a way I can present this excel data in a format to show MARKS for ONLY SUBJECTS that STUDENT has attended the exam as below using some feature in excel? I tried the Pivot table but could not get it. Any help/pointer will be helpful.

```
V  10
   ENG  20
   MAT  19
   HIN  5
   SOC  12
V  11
   ENG  18
   MAT  9
   SCI  16
   ODI  6
V  12
   MAT  5
   SCI  10
   SOC  12
   ART  1
```

See the above [excel document here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZG7xLV4VS5GpDDaPUEn8reIwB7uvr2x8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: You could use Power Query

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, thanks for your input. I never tried the Power Query yet. I will try to explore it. I was thinking if something is possible in excel so that my team can use this.

Comment: Power Query is available in Excel 2010+, either as a free MS provided add-in, or, in Excel 2016+, built-n as `Get & Transform`.  Start with an unpivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had 8 students.

In column P for the roll number and marks:

Starting in cell P1 this would look:

```
=IF(INDEX(A$2:I$9,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(A$2:I$9)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(A$2:I$9),COLUMNS(A$2:G$9))+1)=0,"",INDEX(A$2:I$9,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(A$2:I$9)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(A$2:I$9),COLUMNS(A$2:I$9))+1))
```

Entered as array formula. CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Drag down.

For the classes, you could:

Use this formula for the first block of classes (8 students + the header) from the classes row (A1:I9):

```
=INDEX( A$1:I$1,INT((ROW()-ROW( $A$1 ))/COLUMNS( A$1:I$1 ))+1,MOD(ROW()-ROW( $A$1 ),COLUMNS( A$1:I$1 ))+1)
```

and then this formula imediately after that in row 10, and drag down:

```
=IF(L9="Art",INDEX(A$1:I$1,INT(((ROW()-9)/9+1-ROW($A$1))/COLUMNS(A$1:I$1))+1,MOD(ROW()-9-ROW($A$1),COLUMNS(A$1:I$1))+1),INDEX(A$1:I$1,INT(((ROW()-9)/9+1-ROW($A$1))/COLUMNS(A$1:I$1))+1,MOD(ROW()-9-ROW($A$1),COLUMNS(A$1:I$1))+1))
```

(*Alternatively,* You can copy-paste blocks of the Class & Subjcts. Copy the range A1:I1, paste-transpose. Copy that horizonral segment and paste again it appropriately until youve filled the range).

Either way, Your 2 columns (Roll # & Mark, Class & Subject) should match now.

**There will be blank cells** but your table is now transposed/transformed in 2 corresponding columns. **To remove blank rows,** I would the filter over columns, Select only blanks cells from the marks column. When the filter is done, Highlight those rows (should all be blank in column marks) and delete rows.

Remove filter to see your final data as you wish presented.

Comment: thank you @spyros-tzortzis  for your reply. This looks promising and I will try this today and let you know.